# Problems with C scanf("%c") function to read characters one by one

Tags: c, scanf

The following code produces a very strange result when I run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
         char test;
         printf("Please enter 'w' ");
         scanf("%c", &test);
         printf("%c\n", test);
         if (test == 'w')
         {
              printf("Working\n");
         }
         else
         {
              printf("ERROR\n");
              return 0;
         }
     }
}
```

What I want to happen is for the whenever I input 'w' it continues the loop so I can input 'w' again. What it does though is go to the else statement even though I input 'w'. It just seems to skip the `scanf()` line. I have asked everyone I know who knows C but they do not know how to solve it.

Somebody please help me out here!

Answer (score 10):

This is because you type <kbd>w</kbd> followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. So there are 2 characters in the input, `'w'`, followed by a newline (`\n`). The latter causes the `else` branch to be taken on the second iteration.

Note that standard input is line buffered when connected to a terminal. If you need to deal with characters immediately, there are ways to do that. See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html) for details ("How can I read a single character from the keyboard without waiting for the RETURN key? How can I stop characters from being echoed on the screen as they're typed?").

Note that for robust programming **it is a must to check the return value of `scanf`**. It returns the number of successfully converted items. As shown, your code does not handle the case of end-of-file properly, i.e. when the user types <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> (assuming Unix terminal). Then scanf returns `EOF` and no conversion was performed, but you use `test` as if it contained a meaningful value.

Answer (score 2):

as Jens said. you have to ignore the newline `'\n'`

Adding a space at the beginning of the format specifier `" %c"` will ignore the newline `'\n'`

```
scanf(" %c", &test);
```

Using `" %c"` will also ignore other white spaces like `\t` `space` `\b` `\v` `\r`

Answer (score 1):

As Jens says, you must consume `'\n'`, use `getchar()` after `scanf()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: As you can see, Jens doesn't say nothing about getchar(), so it's not a clarification, is an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
     scanf("%c", &test);
     while(getchar()!='\n');
```

[scanf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) takes input upto space or `\n` (whichever comes first) and leaves the `\n` in the buffer