# scanf("%c") skipped after scanf("%d"), so my lecturer told me to change scanf("%d") to scanf("%s"), but now the code doesn't run properly anymore

Tags: c, scanf

I need some help on my exercise.

[Question of exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQVkF.jpg)

And this was my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int price,new_price;
char code;

printf("Enter the price:");
scanf("%d",&price);
printf("Enter the pricing code:");
scanf("%s",&code);

if(code == 'A')
{
    new_price=price*0.5;
    printf("New discounted price is $%d.00",new_price);
}

else if(code =='B')

{
    new_price=price*0.6;
    printf("New discounted price is $%d.00",new_price);
}
}
```

I know that scanf("%c") gets skipped after input of scanf("%d"), so when I asked my lecturer for a solution , she told me to change scanf("%c") to scanf("%s"). THe problem is , I cannot obtain the new discounted price. The value would show up as $0.00.

This image sums up my problem

[The value shows up as $0.00 even though the code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKeAE.jpg)

I tried using switch and the code works perfectly fine, but I just want to figure out a way to make this code work without using scanf(" %c") formatter.. Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: You changed the input format to `%s` a string type (which skips leading whitespace) but you didn't change the variable type to an array, and you didn't test the first element of that array. Is your teacher a "professor"? Some countries generate "professors" like confetti.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833526 In summary, all you needed to do was change `"%c"` to `" %c"`

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure what you mean by changing the variable type to an array?

Comment: @user3386109 well my teacher told me to change `%c` to `%s` , is there no way to make that work?

Comment: Your variable is `char code;` but the format spec `%s` would require say `char code[100];` and then instead of `if(code == 'A')` you would need `if(code[0] == 'A')`

Comment: The `%s` simply replaces one problem with another. It will skip leading whitespace, and that's good. That's what the space in `" %c"` does. But now you have the problem that it will (potentially) read more than one character, which is not what you want.

Comment: @WeatherVane omg thank you ! this worked like a charm ! But i think from now on I will use `" %c"` as this seems easier

Comment: Which is what the "professor" should have taught you, in the first place.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks again!

Comment: @user3386109 Yes I see that now , and if I use `%s` i need to change my variable type to array also! Thanks!

Comment: @user3386109 Hi can you explain why a space was required to get the input of char.?

Comment: @TheRookieCoder Most conversions (`"%d"`, `"%s"`, `"%f"`, etc.) will automatically skip whitespace (which includes newlines). The `"%c"` conversion is an exception, it doesn't skip whitespace. Putting the space in the conversion `" %c"` causes `scanf` to skip any whitespace that precedes the non-whitespace character that you want.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You put in "`100<enter>A`". Your code is designed to read an integer followed by a character. So it read in "`100`" and then "`<enter>`". You should have put in "`100A<enter>`" if your code is setup to read an integer followed by a character.

If you want to read lines of input and parse them, write code that does that. You can use such a function after you read the integer to read the line ending after it. Then you can read the character.

Comment: But since the exercise requires the `printf` statements to be separated for these two inputs ,I can't really fit in `100A<enter>`

Comment: @BákaVíncentHóng So you didn't write code that did what you wanted. So, now that you see that, change the code to do what you want. For example, add code to read in the `<enter>` after you read the integer but before you read the character.